# anyone please arrange the following big-$O$ notations?

Tags: algorithms

i want to arrange the following notation in ascending order:

$$O(24^n), O(n^2), O(1), O(n\log n)$$

i think $O(1)$ will come first ...

but don't know about others

Comment: How about trying the expressions with $n = 1, 10, 100, ...$?

Answer (score 0):

"i think o(1) will come first... 
second can be o(1)"   WHAT?

O(1)< O(nlogn)< O(n^2)< O(24^n)

Comment: "i think o(1) will come first... second can be o(1)",oops sorry !!!!!!

Comment: Please replace `<` by $\subset$ (subset).

Answer (score 0):

We are interested in understanding how the computational complexity increases as n grows asymptotically. It is clear that $O(1)$ does not grow, so any other function that grows in $n$ will surpass this.

Comparing $n \log (n)$ and $n^2$ first. If we consider
\begin{align*}
\frac{n^2}{n \log(n)} &= \frac{n}{\log(n)}, 
\end{align*}
it is clear that the enumerator dominates as $n$ becomes large. Moreover, it is easy to check that $24^n$ grows faster than $n^2$, by evaluating
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dn} \frac{24^n}{n^2} > 0.
\end{align}

From this, we conclude that $O(1) \subset O(n\log(n)) \subset O(n^2) \subset O(24^n)$